# Adapting existing Convolutional Neural Network model for use with larger images

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm adapting a CNN model that was designed around the CIFAR-10 dataset.

Images in CIFAR-10 are 32x32.  My data set has images that are irregularly shaped, 192x108.

The initial convolution layer has 32 filters, and a 3x3 kernel size, increasing to 64 and then 128 on later layers.

Is it best practice to increase the number of filters, and/or kernel size, if the image size increases?  If so what heuristic should I use?

Does the kernel need to remain symetrical?

Below is my model definition:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
convolution2d_1 (Convolution2D)  (None, 32, 192, 108)  896         convolution2d_input_1[0][0]      
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)              (None, 32, 192, 108)  0           convolution2d_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_2 (Convolution2D)  (None, 32, 192, 108)  9248        dropout_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 32, 96, 54)    0           convolution2d_2[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_3 (Convolution2D)  (None, 64, 96, 54)    18496       maxpooling2d_1[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)              (None, 64, 96, 54)    0           convolution2d_3[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_4 (Convolution2D)  (None, 64, 96, 54)    36928       dropout_2[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 64, 48, 27)    0           convolution2d_4[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_5 (Convolution2D)  (None, 128, 48, 27)   73856       maxpooling2d_2[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)              (None, 128, 48, 27)   0           convolution2d_5[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_6 (Convolution2D)  (None, 128, 48, 27)   147584      dropout_3[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 128, 24, 13)   0           convolution2d_6[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)              (None, 39936)         0           maxpooling2d_3[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)              (None, 39936)         0           flatten_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 1024)          40895488    dropout_4[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)              (None, 1024)          0           dense_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                  (None, 512)           524800      dropout_5[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)              (None, 512)           0           dense_2[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                  (None, 3)             1539        dropout_6[0][0]                  
====================================================================================================
Total params: 41708835
```

Comment: I think you should do the opposite, take a model for larger images (like the ones used for ImageNet) and downscale it a bit. There are no best practices as this completely depends on your data and on learning capacity of the model, so you will have to experiment. One example could be a residual network, and then you experiment to tune how many residual layers you need.